# RGB -> CMYK separation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, printing, colors, rgb, cmyk

I have an image in RGB and I need to create 4 CMYK separation images. Is there an algorithm for that? I have searched for hours and can't find any information about it.

Comment: A CMYK color is expressed in percentages, from zero to 100 percent.  You would take each percentage, and draw the image in cyan, magenta, yellow, and black using the percentage as the amount of hue in the color.

Comment: How do I calculate this percentage? having an (r,g,b) pixel

Comment: That's a separate question.  The formulas for RGB to CMYK are on this [web page](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-cmyk.htm).

Comment: It's not a separate question since I stated that the entry image is in RGB. How do I even take this hue into consideration? I can only drawpixels  in (R,G,B). Do I have to convert to HSV apply the hue and then back to (R,G,B)? How do I choose wheter I want to draw in cyan / magenta / yellow / black ?

Comment: @Greyshack It's really unclear what you're looking for. The link posted by Gilbert gives you the formulas for doing RGB->CMYK conversion. If you need something else, you'll need to clarify that in your question.